# How to go another xaml page xamarin.form FlowListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, navigation

I created FlowListView.FlowLoadingTemplate in xamarin forms. when click on FlowItemTappedCommand go to another page or navigate to other page.

FlowListView xaml:

```
  <StackLayout Padding="10">
    <flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="2"  
                      x:Name="FlowListView"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"   
            HasUnevenRows="True"                  
            FlowTappedBackgroundColor="Red" FlowIsLoadingInfiniteEnabled="True"
            FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"   
            FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <flv:FlowListView.FlowLoadingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    Text="Loading..."
                ></Label>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView.FlowLoadingTemplate>
        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid Padding="5">
                    <BoxView Color="#121E22" Opacity="0.8" CornerRadius="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0">
                    </BoxView>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5" Grid.Row="0">
                        <ff:CachedImage
                            HeightRequest="70" WidthRequest="70" Aspect="AspectFill" 
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                            DownsampleWidth="70" DownsampleUseDipUnits="true"
                            Source ="{Binding Icon}" DownsampleToViewSize="True"
                            LoadingPlaceholder="Spinner.png" 
                            ErrorPlaceholder= "ErrorImage"
                            CacheDuration= "50"
                            RetryCount= "3"
                            RetryDelay= "600"
                            >
                        </ff:CachedImage>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView>
</StackLayout>
```

flow list binding class /cs file

```
 public class ItemPageModel: BindableObject
{
    private ItemsPage itemsPage;
    public ItemPageModel(ItemsPage itemsPage)
    {

        this.itemsPage = itemsPage;
        AddItems();
    }

    private void AddItems()
    {
        Items.Add(new DashboardItemList { Title = "Junction List", Icon = "baseline_view_list_white_48.png", Id = ManuItemList.JunctionList });
        Items.Add(new DashboardItemList { Title = "Live Monitoring", Icon = "baseline_visibility_white_48.png" , Id = ManuItemList.LiveMonitoring });
        Items.Add(new DashboardItemList { Title = "Specification", Icon = "baseline_details_white_36.png" , Id = ManuItemList.Specification });
        Items.Add(new DashboardItemList { Title = "Time Setting", Icon = "baseline_settings_applications_white_48.png", Id = ManuItemList.TimeSetting });
        Items.Add(new DashboardItemList { Title = "Fault Logs", Icon = "baseline_add_alert_white_48.png" , Id = ManuItemList.FaultLogs });
        Items.Add(new DashboardItemList { Title = "Linking Status", Icon = "baseline_link_white_48.png" , Id = ManuItemList.LinkingStatus });
        Items.Add(new DashboardItemList { Title = "Linking Status", Icon = "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8625/15806486058_7005d77438.jpg" });

    }

    private ObservableCollection<DashboardItemList> _items = new ObservableCollection<DashboardItemList>();
    public ObservableCollection<DashboardItemList> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_items != value)
            {
                _items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
            }
        }
    }

    public Command ItemTappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async (sender) =>
            {
                var Item = sender as DashboardItemList;

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new JunctionList());


            });
        }
    }
}
```

}

i tried many way to go to another but i got the exception or app crash

this is my another page where i go when i click the tab

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="MITSAPP.Views.JunctionList">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the MainPage with an Navigation Page in your App.xaml.cs.

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ItemPage());
```

Comment: I already tried in App.xaml.cs. like that   MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());  and in other page i use await Navigation.PushAsync(new JunctionList()); but still i got exception (object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Comment: Are you not navigating from the MainPage.xaml.cs ?

Comment: No,I am navigating from MasterDetailPage , In masterDetailPage has a view "ItemsPage" . So i am navigating from ItemsPage to other content page .

Answer (score 0):

You have to add detail pages also with NavigationPage like below,

```
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <pages:YourDetailPage />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Then you can navigate from a detail page to any pages.

Comment: In master page already have itempage   <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
       <NavigationPage>
           <NavigationPage.Icon>
              <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                  <On Platform="iOS"
                      Value="tab_feed.png" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>                                                                       item page display tab to go other page

Answer (score 0):

I try your code at my side, but I can navigate to another page when tapped FlowListView item, I have no issue, here is my sample, you can download to test.

https://github.com/CherryBu/Sample1

I see you said that you navigated from MasterDetailedPage, if you still have issue, can you upload your sample at github, I will download you sample to test.